# Regex: not a backslash or line start

Tags: regex, sed

In a text file I need to remove non-escaped characters like in the following example

```
"\\s" -> "\s"
"\s" -> ""
```

I need to use **sed** for this excercise. I made this command:

```
s/\([^\]\)\\s/\1/g
s/\\\\/\\/g
```

The problem I now encounter is the fact that `\s` at the beginning of a line is not beïng removed. What sould be added to the regex to acomplish this. I also tried the `*` and `?` but the problem with these is that they also remove the  `\\s` strings.

So I really need a way to match 'not a backslash or a line start'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo '\s xxxxx \\s yyyyy \s zzzzz \\s \\s end' |
sed 's/\\s/\n/g;s/\\\n/\\s/g;s/\n//g'
xxxxx \s yyyyy  zzzzz \s \s end
```

a three step process:

1. Change `\s` to `\n`
2. Change `\\n` to `\s`
3. Delete `\n`'s i.e. the original `\s`'s

N.B. I use `\n` because it cannot appear in the original line as sed uses it as a line delimiter.